# fatal error: Eigen/Eigenvalues in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Currently, I am trying to install opencv3.0 on my ubuntu machine but I am getting an error message when I type the `make` command.

This is my error message:

```
/home/innovation/opencv-3.0.0/modules/calib3d/src/dls.cpp:11:31: fatal error: Eigen/Eigenvalues: No such file or directory
#  include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_calib3d.dir /src/dls.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_calib3d.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

this is the cmake code:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON ..
```

Can I know what the way to solve this error. I have tried reinstalling my Python but still the same. I am using `python2.7.10`

Comment: This error is not about python, it is about eigen.  It seems you didnot configure cmake in the right way. reconfigure and specify the location of eigen library

Comment: i have edited my question with the cmake in it

Answer (score 3):

After installing [Eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/) (via previous reply with `apt` or suggestion below), make sure that `cmake` is looking at eigen3 and not eigen2.

I used macports to get eigen3, so it looks like:

```
sudo port install eigen3
```

And the Cmake option:

```
EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include/eigen3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing package

```
sudo apt-get install libeigen3-dev
```

Worked for me in similar situation

Answer (score 0):

Add "-D WITH_EIGEN=OFF" in your cmake script.